# Seeing error: session must be <requests.session.Session object> not <class 'str'> - Not sure what it means

Tags: python

I am experimenting with IG Markets and trying to run the below:

```
response = ig_service.fetch_client_sentiment_by_instrument('GBPUSD','NZDGBP')
print(response)
```

But I see this error:

File "C:\Users\Barry\Desktop\IG Trading\ig-markets-api-python-library-master\trading_ig\rest.py", line 211, in _get_session
    % type(session)
AssertionError: session must be  not

Please note, it only happens when there is more than one marketid used: ('GBPUSD','NZDGBP').The request below works:

```
response = ig_service.fetch_client_sentiment_by_instrument('GBP')
print(response)
```

Code below shows actual declarations

```
def fetch_client_sentiment_by_instrument(self, market_id, session=None):
    """Returns the client sentiment for the given instrument's market"""
    params = {}
    if isinstance(market_id, (list,)):
        market_ids = ','.join(market_id)
        url_params = {
            'market_ids': market_ids
        }
        endpoint = '/clientsentiment/?marketIds={market_ids}'.\
            format(**url_params)
    else:
        url_params = {
            'market_id': market_id
        }
        endpoint = '/clientsentiment/{market_id}'.format(**url_params)
    action = 'read'
    response = self._req(action, endpoint, params, session)
    data = self.parse_response(response.text)
    if self.return_munch:
        from .utils import munchify
        data = munchify(data)
    return(data)


def _get_session(self, session):
    """Returns a Requests session (from self.session) if session is None
    or session if it's not None (cached session with requests-cache
    for example)
    """
    if session is None:
        session = self.session  # requests Session
    else:
        assert(isinstance(session, Session)), \
            "session must be <requests.session.Session object> not %s" \
            % type(session)
        session = session
    return session
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your function sees 'GBPUSD','NZDGBP', its assigning NZDGBP to the session variable and hence crashing.

Try running:

response = ig_service.fetch_client_sentiment_by_instrument(['GBPUSD','NZDGBP'])

Mow its a single list and should function as expected

Answer (score 1):

The third argument to `fetch_client_sentiment_by_instrument` defaults to `None`. If you supply a value for it, you are expected to pass in a suitable `session` object (this allows you to override the default behavior of `requests`, such as when you want to use a particular TLS version instead of whatever you get out of the box for HTTPS connections). It's not meant for passing in additional `market_id` identifiers, as you can readily tell from the function's definition.

(The method call supplies an implicit first argument,  so the method's third argument comes from the second explicit argument in the method call, as generally everywhere in Python where the first argument is `self`.)